# 400 error for https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token post request React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rest, azure-active-directory

I am trying to do a post request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token in react typescript application
[image]

I am getting a 400 error while making a post request   in my React Typescript Application

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above requirement, You need to use the below workaround.

***When you are adding client id and client secret ,In this case there is no need to provide username and password.***

You can achieve this with client id and client secret and adding scope to it.

To get the scope details you can find as below:
[image]

***SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-***
In `grant type` use "client credential" instead of `password`
[image]